# Exec не работает

Tags: gcc, exec, c, linux

Собираю программу на gcc под debian jessie.
В программе необходимо вызвать exec.

После того как перед вызовом добавил одно функцию, после неё exec перестал срабатывать.
Проверял на execv("hello",NULL). В папке с программой есть файл hello.
Вызвал до функции - сработало.
Вызвал после функции - не сработало.
Закомментировал содержимое функции - работает.

П.С.: Правда, дальше exec тоже странно себя ведёт.

Куда с таким случаем обратиться? Может быть, это глюк нестабильного ядра?

Вот функция:
Основная часть закомментирована, и возвращён подставленный ответ.

```
    // ==================================================
// ==================================================
int get_config(char *ans)
{
/*
char buff[256];
strcpy(ans,"");
strcpy(buff,"");
char cmp[9];

FILE *faddr = fopen("autotest_config.txt","r");
if ( faddr == 0 )
{
        printf(RED "Файл конфигурации autotest_config.txt не существует.\n Генерирую шаблон для редактирования.." RESET);
        write_conf();
        return 0;
} else  {

        while ( fgets( buff ,256,faddr ) ) // В этом if выполняется чтение из файла
        {
        if (strlen(buff)>8) { strncpy(cmp,buff,8); cmp[8]=0; printf("cmp=%s\n",cmp);
                                if (!strcmp(cmp,"binpath=")) { strcpy(ans,buff+8); printf("ans=%s\n",ans); }
                            }
        }
        printf("finished while\n");
        fclose(faddr);
}
printf("returning,%p\n",ans);
if (strlen(ans)<1) return 0;
return 1;
*/

strcpy(ans,"abc");
return 1;
}
```

**Обновление**

Всем спасибо за внимание, пока составлял минимальный код, проблема как-то исчезла.

Видимо, переполнялся стек, переменная, в которую возвращался ans была описана как:

```
char *path;
```

Я заменил на

```
char path[256];
```

Кроме этого, программа, которую я запускаю почему-то запускается только через execl() с параметрами командной строки (а без них падает), это к странному поведению с закомменченой функцией.

Comment: а в ans точно есть достаточно места, что бы скопировать результат? valgrin пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего где-то порится память.

Все же, приведите законченный код **минимального примера** в котором execv() не работает. Попробуем разобраться.

Минимальный *работающий пример* execv() может быть, например, таким:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat e.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  execv(av[1], av);
  perror("execv");

  exit(1);
}
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat e.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello $*
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gcc e.c ; ./a.out e.sh 1 2 3
Hello e.sh 1 2 3
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

**Обновление**

По поводу "почему-то запускается только через execl()...".

Вы пишите

```
execv("hello",NULL)
```

Похоже Вы немного перепутали как передавать параметры в execl и execv.
Для вызова аналогичного sh > ./cmd arg1 arg2

```
 char *args[] = {"cmd", "arg1", "arg2", 0};
```

execv:

```
 execv(args[0], args);
```

execl:

```
 execl(args[0], args[0], args[1], args[2], 0);
```

А лучше сами почитайте `man execv`.

Answer (score 0):

если переменная объявлена как `char *path`, а память под нее не больше не выделяется, то `strcpy(ans,"abc");` и другие подобные куски кода могут приводить к самым призабавнейшим спецэффектам.

Comment: да, точно, не переполнялся стек, а была запись не по тому адресу, получается так